# Meteor Mongo aggregate returns BSON type

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, bson

I have the below aggregate query

```
var pipeline=[ { $match: { Active:1, Duration:'monthly' } },{ $sample: { size: 3 } }]
Products.aggregate(pipeline).toArray((err, result) => {
  subscription.added('random-aggregate', 'random-order', { result: result });
});
```

it returns the correct result but the ObjectId is in BSON type which makes it difficult to further process it. How can I get the correct Object id of the collection record?
Attached a screenshot how the id looks on console [image]

Although when checking the MiniMongo Meteor screen the id looks normal and also in other queries I use among the project the id is in the correct format[image]

Comment: Isn't the `_id` (as an `ObjectId` already correct?   Are you asking if there's a way to (for example) toString() the `ObjectId` so you don't have to cart around the object itself?

Comment: Hi @BuzzMoschetti I have attached 2 screenshots that show how the id arrives in console after the aggregation although in other cases I see it in the normal format.

Comment: The console is evaluating the `ObjectId` object as a pure byte array; in fact, an `ObjectId` is a 12 byte sequence of data.   Other environments will typically try `toString()` or equiv when they encounter an object type that they do not know.   That's what is happening here.   An `ObjectId` is *not* a string; it is an `ObjectId`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you must have solved the issue by now, just in case anyone else runs into this...

> save products in a variable, then clone the array like this,
>
> `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(products))`